# How to recreate new documents and desktop folders that I accidentally deleted (Monterey 12.5)

Tags: icloud, finder, folders

Mac newbie here, please be gentle!

I can no longer see the desktop and document folders on my MacBook (ie, they don't show up in finder) after accidentally deleting them, or doing something daft like that.

I haven't lost content, as my documents and desktop folder still show up fine in iCloud, with all the content in.

I want to be able to see the documents folder on my laptop files hierarchy in finder, and put stuff in it (and know it will get automatically synced to the cloud). (Ditto the desktop folder - though I can at least currently drag stuff onto desktop and it is then synced into the iCloud desktop folder).

I tried going into Preferences / Add to Sidebar, but the desktop and documents folders are not showing up there as an option.

I tried simply recreating these folders in finder, and it told me they already exist.

As I said, I have both folders showing in my iCloud account. Should I simply copy across from there to my hard drive by dragging and dropping? I don't understand sync very well and am just slightly concerned this might be a bad way of doing it (we're also talking several GB of data).

I am terrified of losing the stuff I have on iCloud. I'm mid getting everything sorted so I don't have a hard drive back up yet.

Full disclosure, I also have an iPhone, and a new iMac that DOES show the desktop and documents folders - but they aren't currently set to sync with iCloud, so they are empty.

I just want a set up that keeps everything synced to the cloud wherever I create it, and where I can visually navigate around the file structure in finder/files, on each device.

Many thanks!

(EDIT - just to clarify, in case this bit confused anyone - the reason my documents folder in iCloud has all my data, is that I migrated it all across from another service altogether - my data was never really stored on this newish MacBook, but I've realised it was a mistake to delete the empty documents folder on here, as that's what I should be using to keep everything synced...I think!)

Comment: In the Finder's Go menu, can you select Documents or Desktop? On another point: it's really important that you have a backup copy of your documents. iCloud Drive is not a backup, as if you delete a file from there, it gets deleted everywhere.

Comment: I’d sign out of iCloud to prevent any synchronization, create a new user account, log into that then re-sign into iCloud using the newly created account so that it syncs cleanly.

Comment: I can indeed select Go_documents / desktop - it takes me to the iCloud folders. I know that I need it saved not just on the iCloud, that's why I'm trying to figure out the best way of getting these folders back on the MacBook, with the content in them there too. I really would prefer not to create another iCloud account (I have got into such a muddle having various accounts on various services in the past), is there not another way?